# Typescript - Is there a way to have default value for union of literal types if none from union is chosen?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, union

For example if I have a type like this => size?: "small" | "medium" | "large"
And if somebody chooses size = "super_small", I'd like it to default to "medium" for example.
Is there a way to do this without having to manually check every time what the user has provided?

I'm creating a library in typescript and it will be used in a javascript project so instead of size having options from the union, it's just gonna convert it to string.

I tried googling but cant figure it out. Please help

Comment: At runtime or compiletime?

Comment: at runtime is fine

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a constant array which you can derive the original union type from first:

```
const choices = ["small", "medium", "large"] as const;
```

Then the union can be retrieved like this:

```
type Choices = typeof choices[number];
```

Your function can then take `Choices | string & {}` and check if the input is included in `choices`:

```
function accept(c: Choices | string & {}) {
    if (!choices.includes(c as Choices)) c = "medium";
}
```

You use `string & {}` instead of `string` so that the union doesn't collapse to `string` and still provides autocomplete:

```
accept("large");
//     ^^^^^^^ autocompleted with intellisense
accept("asdfg");
//     ^^^^^^^ but this is still okay
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36R3N)